# NestJS - How to handle global exception in non-api application in

Tags: nestjs

I have a sample application created in NestJs which does not have a single controller. I have created global exception filter and injected it via app module like:

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_FILTER,
            useClass: CustomExceptionFilter,
        },
    ]
```

When any service method called and exception occurs, call is not coming in my custom exception filter. Note that I have not a single controller in my application. There are modules and services only.

Also I have tried registering my custom filter in main.ts which is not working:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new CustomExceptionFilter());
```

I want to handle exceptions of all type using global exception filter only. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a solution for your question?

Answer (score 4):

The global aproach is ok you only need to put an empty catch decorator at the beggining of the class and it will catch all the errors

```
@Catch()
export class CustomExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done that only. Because I want to catch all exceptions. Not just any specific one.

Comment: understood, but if you don't define what are you catching inside the decorator it will catch all the exceptions, if that is not the behavior you are getting you are doing something wrong, can you update with the exception filter code you are using?